# using has_many: primary_key when it isn't the primary_key in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm working on a codebase that uses `rails` and the previous developers have created a few models in `postgres` that are references to each other. However they use `activerecord`'s `primary_key` field even though the database doesn't show that field as the `primary_key`. Is there any benefit or disadvantage to this? Keep in mind there is an index on the 'fake' `primary_key` field .

```
# models
class A < ActiveRecord:Base
    has_many :bs, primary_key: :special_id
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :a, primary_key: :special_id, foreign_key: :special_id
end
```

Actual primary_key is `id` on `B` but schema includes `id` and `special_id`. Index exists on `special_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit, in theory, is that it's more readable. In your case `A.find(id).bs` would join the `B`s that have a corresponding `b_id` in your `A` table, which may not be as intuitive as using another name, in this case `special_id`.

From a performance standpoint it should make no noticeable difference, provided there are indexes on both the primary and foreign key columns. The `has_many` method will ultimately result in a query, so the only computational cost is to swap out the column name in the query string that `ActiveRecord` generates.

You could try benchmarking the queries with the various key declarations, but I'd be amazed if it added even a millisecond to the query time.